# dbm package: file is not a database on open with SQLITE viewer

Tags: python, sqlite, dbm

I made a database with the Python package dbm but I cannot seem to find any way to open it. The file is recognizable for reading and writing but when I try to open it visually using SQLITE viewer, it gives back: "An error occurred: file is not a database".
Here is how I open and write one thing but I cannot view it with a VS code extension:

```
with dbm.open('cache', 'c') as db:
    db['www.python.org'] = 'Python Website'
```

Answer (score 1):

The dbm package is NOT SQLite. The SQLite package is called "sqlite3"

Comment: Yeah I know that but how do I open it?

Comment: With Python, the same way you created it. There are probably other tools as well. The question is why using this format instead of SQLite?